# CodeContract think assigned readonly field can be null

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I've got this code:

```
public class CodeContractSample
{
    private readonly List<object> _items = new List<object>();

    public IEnumerable<object> Query()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<object>>() != null);
        //if (_items == null) throw new Exception();
        return _items;
    }
}
```

CodeContracts gives this warning:

> CodeContracts: ensures unproven: Contract.Result>() != null

If I uncomment the middle row it stops complaining. But why does it complain to start with? _items should never be null..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Contracts are not 100% and there are still gaps in what it understands.**

You are right: there is no reason for the result being unproven. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/f82aa25c-e858-4809-bc21-0a08de260bf1 for more information on this specific issue.

For now, you can solve this using:

```
Contract.Assume(_items != null);
```

You can also achieve this using contract invariants:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
void Invariants()
{
    Contract.Invariant(_items != null);
}
```

Comment: Nice, this is also useful after some of my Asserts in my unit tests... :)

Comment: It would be cleaner to solve it with an invariant, like this: `[ContractInvariantMethod] void Invariants() { Contract.Invariant(_items != null); }`. Otherwise, you need to Assume all over the place :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think items will never be null? You could have another method in that class that sets it to null ...

Comment: It's readonly. Only the constructor could set it to null. But I don't have any constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i can imagine this:

```
CodeContractSample s = new CodeContractSample();
s.GetType().GetField("_items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(s, null);
var q = s.Query();
```

What do You think ?

Comment: Yes, that could happen. But then the contract would throw an exception at runtime. When doing things with reflection I can no longer expect that the static compile-time checker would give me warnings.

Answer (score -1):

The Contract.Ensures line is making a promise that the method will never return null.  But there is nothing in the code that prevents this until you uncomment the line.

Comment: ...except that `_items` is initialised in the class the constructor and `Query` is a non-static method.

Comment: I don't think that kind of functionality has been implemented yet.  It would require a change to the c# language.  See http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/494357-Design-by-Contract-in-C/0ef9306b38314b1aa4c09deb0009144e